# VS Code: Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

I wanted to change the theme of my VS Code and I got an Error: **Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to correct errors/warnings in it and try again.**

When I open the user settings, a settings.json file is opened and here's the code of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The json file has another Error: **Expected a JSON object, array or literal. jsonc[1,1]**

I am unable to change a lot of settings that would speed up my productivity. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your settings.json file contains invalid JSON.
Visual Studio Code is unable to modify your settings.json file (which drives all your user defined settings) when the file contains invalid JSON and notifies you with this error. The code snippet you included looks like C++ code, which obviously is not JSON. Delete that out of the setting.json file.

If this is *the only* text in your settings.json file, then deleting it all should resolve that error, since I believe a default install has no properties defined in the settings.json file, but double check first.